# Squid transparency except for SSL/HTTPS

Tags: squid

How would you set up squid so that everything else is transparent (e.g FTP, HTTP, etc.) except for SSL/HTTPS which needs to be set manually?

Will I need to change my firewall rules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't make everything transparent with Squid. Only HTTP can be transparent and HTTPS with a non recommended hack. For FTP, you need a pure FTP proxy like Frox.

Anyway, it doesn't make any sense to use proxies if you want to make everything transparent, use NAT.

HTTP could be useful only because the cache.